# Limit coverity scan to main and dev, to stop covering feature branches

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, coverity

I am trying to setup yml for coverity scan in Devops only for main and dev and not other branches

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 3 * * 1-7"
  displayName: Daily late night coverity run
  branches:
    include:
    - main
    - dev
  always: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your script will work as your expection. This version of the YAML file are checked into the main and dev branches not others.

You could also refer to this doc for details: [Scheduled triggers in YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers)

[image]